# Different types, single module

Tags: types, vhdl

I was wondering if it is possible to use (instantiate) the same (vhdl) module with different types. For example, some of its input/output ports would be arrays of different length?

One option is:

```
    component PARITY
    generic (N : integer);
    port    (A : in  std_ulogic_vector
                (N-1 downto 0);
             ODD : out std_ulogic);
    end component;
```

But I'd like std_ulogic_vector(N-1 downto 0) to be predefined as a type.

Maybe some parametrized (generic) package used inside or outside of PARITY?

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks!

Comment: yes. Just like you say.. Use VHDL-2008. Then you can even put `T: type` in the generic list.

Comment: Right, but if there are several (/many) types then I'll have to redefine them again and again in the generic of any module?

Comment: you could set a default value: `generic(T : type := std_logic_vector(9 downto 0));`. If you want a default range of another parameter (e.g. `N`, thus `N-1 downto 0`), then you should use a generic package.

Comment: Any good reference for generic packages? Thanks!

Comment: I put some code in an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324918/vhdl-function-procedure-for-any-type-of-array/43327348#43327348). Difficult to find a good source online. Maybe [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/How-to-use-generic-packages-as-introduced-in-VHDL-2008/td-p/705147)?

Answer (score 1):

VHDL-2008 allows you to have interface types (types in a generic clause and generic map aspect).

**Entity declaration:**

```
entity E1 is
  generic (
    type myType
  );
  port (
    Clock   : std_logic;
    Inputs  : myType;
    Outputs : myType
  );
end entity;

architecture rtl of E1 is
begin
  -- Outputs(Outputs'left) <= Inputs(Inputs'right);
end architecture;
```

**Entity usage:**

```
entity E2 is
end entity;

architecture rtl of E2 is
  constant N1 : positive := 8;
  subtype ST1 is std_logic_vector(N1 - 1 downto 0);
begin
  inst : entity work.E1
    generic map (
      myType => ST1
    )
    port map (
      Clock   => '0',
      Inputs  => (others => '1'),
      Outputs => open
    );
end architecture;
```

**So that's the theory. Now comes the disadvantages:**

- Support in synthesis is rare.
- You can't use `Inputs` and `Outputs` like an array in `E1`, because the type is an incomplete interface type. The tool will not know that myType maps to an array type and that e.g. index and slice operations are allowed. The same goes for attributes. As no knowledge about the type is available, `'left` and `'right` won't work.

That's why I wrote major parts of [LCS-2016-059](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_059) for VHDL-2017.

---

**Alternative**

Instead of passing a generic parameter `N`, you can also use unconstrained ports in entities - if supported by your tool :).

```
entity E1 is
  port (
    Clock   : std_logic;
    Inputs  : std_logic_vector;
    Outputs : Inputs'range
  );
end entity;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and examples. This sounds like what I hoped for but since I have several arrays of different types (all parametrized by a single parameter), the generic list will be long and kind of repetitive among the various modules exchanging these IOs. I wish to avoid code repetition and hence perhaps a parameterised package will be the solution, but I still need to dig into it.